# Guess the Disney song from the initials number 9

Tags: music

Guess the song from the initials of the lyrics.

I N T H E
T C A U P
B M T G A G O P
I A T M V A B

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with these puzzles individually, you've posted 9 of them in the last hour and a half.  I think it's time to take a break for a while.  If people see too many of these pop up in a short time period, they are likely to get annoyed and start downvoting.

Comment: I have just been taking a break and looking for some questions to answer

Comment: Very strongly agree with GentlePurpleRain. @WilliamPennanti, please do not do this. One a day is a reasonable limit, and for (sorry, but I must be frank) rather uninteresting puzzles like these, even that is a bit much.

Comment: Sorry. I just was a bit bored so wanted to do these and El-Guest seemed to really be enjoying them. I won't do anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This song is

> "Be Prepared", by Scar in the Lion King

Comment: It is. I'm doing some beatles songs now

Comment: It took me a long time to figure out which part of the song this is.  I was expecting the animated movie version.